# jquery disable paste images into texteditor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using texteditor
I would like to disable the option to copy/paste images into it. so i add jquery code that get the paste content and block if it's contain "data:image".

i did it because images contain the string: "src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS......."

if i paste text that contain the string than the code works fine, but it's not blocking when i paste images. why is that?

alert show nothing when i paste image. see here:

http://77.247.180.36/~pelegisr/sites/support-V3/admin/textarea.html

jquery:

```
$('.note-editable, #editor-area').bind('paste',function(e) { 
// var pastedText = $(this).val();
   var pastedText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
   alert( pastedText);

   if(pastedText.indexOf('data:image')!== -1 || pastedText.indexOf('src="data:image"')!== -1 || pastedText.indexOf('base64')!== -1)    {
       e.preventDefault(); 
   }     
});
```

Comment: It's not text, so I'd not expect `.getData("text")` to return anything.  Change the alert to `console.log(e.originalEvent.clipboardData);` and just inspect the object in the console.

Comment: I added the Javascript tag as this question is really a Javascript question.  I left the jQuery tag as you're using it, despite your issue having nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Archer - alert is empty...why is  that? I update the link above with your code

Comment: Actually, the editor you're using is the cause of your problems.  It handles clipboard events itself.  Search this page for "paste".... https://summernote.org/deep-dive/   You can capture the paste event with `$(document).on("summernote.paste", function etc..`